# How much PHP memory_limit is required?

Tags: php, codeigniter, memory, memory-limit

My website runs on a dedicated server with 8GB of RAM. By default the memory_limit is set to 32MB.

How to find out the correct `memory_limit` requirement for my website? What factors affect the `memory_limit` setting? Do the factors like traffic on website or number of concurrent requests etc affect it or cause errors like "allowed memory size exhausted errors?

Comment: Traffic, amount of inefficient code you have running that's not cleaning up after itself, etc.

Comment: I don't know if there is a "correct" value for the memory_limit. Typically you would allow it to use as much ram as you need. As in based off what the server is supposed to do. Are you opening large files? Are you running a pre-made packge? Any large pre-made software package should have a recommendation and I would suggest going with that. PHP will throw an error if the memory limit it hit.

Comment: You'll [find this](https://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) to be very useful in determining your peak RAM usage per process. If you add it to your usual logging, you can get an idea what user actions cause what usage. You then want to set your process size to the maximum plus a safety margin, to allow for small increases (maybe a few M over your maximum).

Answer (score 2):

You can change the memory limit by changing `memory_limit` in the `php.ini` or setting it dynamically:

```
ini_set("memory_limit", "256M");
```

How much memory you need depends on what you're doing. A typical website won't need that much. 32MB sounds fine. Some processes might require more memory, for instance resizing uploaded images or generating statistics.

High traffic doesn't affect PHP's ability to allocate memory, that is the OS's problem. Your webserver limits how many workers it has and thus how much memory PHP could use it if tried to take it all. It might make things mighty slow though.